# System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, ravendb

I get this exception, any thoughts how to fix? I know its something stupid but can't seem to figure it out.

Expression type not supported:

System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN

```
public static IQueryable<T> GetBy<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        try
        {
            IDocumentSession RavenSession = MvcApplication.Store.OpenSession();
            var t = RavenSession.Query<T>().Where(predicate);
            RavenSession.Dispose();
            //return t.AsQueryable<T>();
            return t;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

var r = DB.GetBy<Docs>(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault(); <-- this is where I get the exception
```

Comment: Get rid of that evil `catch` block.

Comment: Disposing the session before using the query is unlikely to work.

Comment: Yes, @SLaks you are right of course.

Comment: @Slaks you should have posted your comment as an answer to give you the credit.

Comment: When you get the error, what does `predicate` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't dispose the session before using the query.